# Can two processes running on a smartphone communicate with their corresponding apps running on pc at the same time over bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a Huawei Ascend G700 smartphone. I connect it successfully every time with my laptop via Bluetooth. I have an android application of my own which sends data to a server running on PC via Bluetooth. Whenever I launch my application on my smartphone and try to connect it to the server (already up and running) via Bluetooth, it does not connect.
When I connect my smartphone with laptop via Bluetooth, the laptop automatically starts receiving the phone calls and I can answer them from there.
I tried but was unable to stop this thing from happening. What I suspect is that because Bluetooth channel is already engaged by that call receiving process! that is why my application cannot connect to the server running on PC. Is my suspicion correct? If it is, please help me in solving it.

Comment: some screenshots would help

Comment: what sort of screenshots you think will be hellpful?